# Excel VBA multiple For loop not working

Tags: vba, excel

I seem to be stuck in an weird issue. I have the Excel VBA code below to visit a website and enter a userID (from the userID column A in sheet 1) and retrieve the name of the user which shows up after hitting the submit button then continues with the rest of the userIDs.

```
Public Sub TEST()
TestPage = "http://test.com/"

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim GetElem As Object
Dim GetElem2 As Object

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate TestPage
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))

Set Doc = IE.document
CurRow = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Do While CurRow > 0
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:4"))

    'Find/Get the userID textbox and enter the current userID
    For Each GetElem In Doc.getElementsByTagName("input")
        If GetElem.ID = "query" Then 'I could just do getElementByID later
            GetElem.Value = Sheet1.Range("A" & CurRow).Value
        End If
    Next

    'Find and click the submit button        
    For Each GetElem2 In Doc.getElementsByTagName("button")
        If GetElem2.Type = "submit" Then
            GetElem2.Click
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
        End If
    Next
    CurRow = CurRow - 1
Loop
End Sub
```

The problem is the code works only once. It enters the first userID into the text box and hits Submit. When it loops and tries to enter the next userID though, the code get stuck in a loop.

If I remove the entire 2nd For-Next loop it works (although it doesn't submit, it enters each of the userIDs in the text box).

On top of that, if I use the F8 debugging the code step by step, everything works fine. Only getting problems when fully running the code.:(

Comment: Put a `debug.print CurRow` before the `Loop` and check the value it is giving in the immediate window.

Comment: It is stuck in a loop.  CurRow is always greater than zero.  Each time it passes through, it starts the "For Each GetElem In Doc.getElementsByTagName("input")" all over again - so it will always cgo to the first instance - every loop.  You need to get rid of the Do While CurRow > 0 loop.  try putting all .query names into an array first, and then use for i = lbound(myArray) to ubound(myArray)

Comment: I don't understand :( I can see you're on to something and you might have seen the problem but I'm scratching my head over here. Why did you say CurRow is always greater than zero? I mean CurRow starts as sheet1.usedrange.rows.count which is 78 then it is reduced by 1 every time it loops in the Do-While loop

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub TEST()
TestPage = "http://test.com/"

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim GetElem As Object
Dim GetElem2 As Object

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate TestPage
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))

Set Doc = IE.document
CurRow = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For Each GetElem In Doc.getElementsByTagName("input")
        If GetElem.ID = "query" Then 'I could just do getElementByID later
            GetElem.Value = Sheet1.Range("A" & CurRow).Value
            For Each GetElem2 In Doc.getElementsByTagName("button")
                If GetElem2.Type = "submit" Then
                    GetElem2.Click
                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
                End If
            Next GetElem2
        End If
        CurRow = CurRow + 1
    Next GetElem

End Sub
```